# Change taxonomy for categories

Tags: php, taxonomy

I am using a plugin called "Recent posts widget extended" with a directory theme where i have directory listings showing as adverts in a sidebar on specific pages.

The plugin allows me to show posts from specific categories on certain pages.

The directory listings are in categories but not normal WP categories, they are within the themes own categories where the taxonomy name is "ait-dir-item-category"

These directory categories are not selectable using the plugin, only the normal categories which are not in use.

I have tried to edit the plugin PHP file (there is only one file to the plugin) changing
    `$categories = get_terms( 'category' );`
to 
    `$categories = get_terms( 'ait-dir-item-category' );`
but this had no effect.

I wonder if you could assist me in changing what taxonomy the plugin looks for for the categories please so that I can filter via the theme categories and not the default WP categories.

Thanks.

The select list is as follows:

```
<?php $categories = get_terms( 'category' ); ?> 
<?php foreach( $categories as $category ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" <?php if ( is_array( $cat ) && in_array( $category->term_id, $cat ) ) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
        <?php echo $category->name; ?>
    </option>
```

Comment: You may have better help asking the plugin community. They'll know best what to look for and what to change. [Recent Posts Widget Extended Support](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/recent-posts-widget-extended)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - Thanks, i've already posted in the plugin support forum, just thought with it being just one simple PHP file and the select box being populated somehow with categories, it might be a simple fix for someone with more PHP knowledge than me :-)

Comment: Are you talking about in the front-end or back-end? If it's in the back-end then that means it's plugin specific and if you edit any of the plugin files, they will be overwritten when the plugin updates.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - it's in the backend but i've already warned the client they can't update this particular plugin if it's edited which seems the only way this can be sorted.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - The plugin/widget has a select box populated with wp categories, which I want populated with the themes categories instead so these are selectable. The code for the select box is:
`<?php $categories = get_terms( 'category' ); ?>
     <?php foreach( $categories as $category ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" <?php if ( is_array( $cat ) && in_array( $category->term_id, $cat ) ) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>` 
and i tried to change the taxonomy name from category to ait-dir-item-category but this didn't work.

Comment: In theory, if your taxonomy is called `ait-dir-item-category` it does look like that should work unless there's more to the plugin. I'm entirely unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - I tried it again and it worked, my drop down is now populated with the themes categories and are selectable which is great. Unfortuntely the posts don't show under these on the page, could this be something to do with the post query? I could post the relevant code in pastebin if that helps. Thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: It may be helpful, but it may also be better to find a more suitable plugin than editing one and telling your client not to update it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - I have just looked at a few different plugins and it seems all that let you show posts from specific categories only pull in the category list from 'category' so all would need editing in this way to list the correct categories for me.

Comment: You should **NOT** use hyphens in taxonomy names. This totally breaks everything

Comment: @PieterGoosen the taxonomy names were created by the AIT Themes Directory theme itself

Comment: @Adrian that is just poor practice from the author. I did answer and explain this in my answer to one of your other questions. The use of hypens is your problem in both questions unfortunetely.